# Scraping Tweets from a Specific URL in Python

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

I've been testing out the following Python code:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib

api_key = "a"
api_secret = "b"
access_token_key = "c"
access_token_secret = "d"

_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"


http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

'''
Construct, sign, and open a twitter request
using the hard-coded credentials above.
'''
def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=http_method,
                                             http_url=url, 
                                             parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if http_method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response

def fetchsamples():
  url = "myURL"
  parameters = []
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  for line in response:
    print line.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fetchsamples()
```

The goal, as I understand it, of this code is to fetch tweets from a specific URL 'myURL'. However, when I run it I get a whole bunch of front end HTML and JavaScript, but no tweets. Am I mistaken about the purpose of this code? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What is you `myURL`? Is it a valid API call?

Comment: @TerenceEden Sorry, it's of the form https://twitter.com/example (any regular twitter page)

Comment: That's not how you call the Twitter API.  I suggest you start by reading the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue when doing the twitter assignment in a course from Coursera.
Finally I need to look at doc in twitter 
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user

```
response = oauth_req(URL, access_token_key, access_token_secret )
```

I doubt SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 is not necessary.